# How to get object of PersonalizationProvider of WebParts in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts, webpartpage

There is [SqlPersonalizationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478955.aspx) and I have also defined other `CustomPersonalizationProvider` In the page where I have multiple webparts, I need to have functionality to reset the state of Webparts to emply or delete the state.

There exists a defined method `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationProvider.ResetState` which can be called, with page path and username. I could not find a way to get object of current provider, so I can call this method to delete state.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can get Current Providers using `PersonalizationAdministration.Provider` and to reset state there are methods in providers like:

```
PersonalizationAdministration.Provider.ResetState(PersonalizationScope.Shared, paths, null);
or
PersonalizationAdministration.Provider.ResetState(PersonalizationScope.Private, paths, username);
```